# Jersey ReST app running on Glassfish 4.1, endpoint gives 404

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey-2.0, glassfish-4

I have a Jersey (2.15) ReSTful application running on GlassFish 4.1 and again, running on a Mac OS X (10.9.5). Should be a breeze to get an example app running and an endpoint producing funky stuff? The reality is that it seems to be one gigantic headache. The application can deploy but the ReSTful endpoints are not available, i.e. they return a 404.

The logs tell me everything is working dandy. The same application (with a little library tweaking) works comfortably in Tomcat 7. I just do not know enough about Glassfish and it's working innards to come up with a solution.

pom.xml has these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And my class:

```
@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getClichedMessage() {
        // Return some cliched textual content
        return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

web.xml (although it seems one is not required):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>example</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Admin tool tells me app is running and can be found at /RCKMS-RS. So, invoking the ReSTful endpoint *should* be an HTTP GET at /RCKMS-RS/rest/helloworld

Deployment is fine with no errors. I suppose my question is: Is there some configuration in Glassfish that I need to change to expose these endpoints?

Comment: Please update the question with your `web.xml` and the URL you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you got it to work in Tomcat, but this right here

```
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
```

would prevent it from working anywhere. This is not a property in Jersey 2. If you are using *anything* with the prefix `com.sun.jersey`, and you are using Jersey 2, then assume there is something wrong. Everything is Jersey 2 starts with `org.glassfish.jersey`, So the correct property you should use is

```
<param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
```

---

> web.xml (although it seems one is not required):

True, one is not required, but then you need an `Application/ResourceConfig` subclass, As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28129465/2587435) and in [Application Deployment and Runtime Environments](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html)

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet, I gave up and needed to get moving, "time is money and money is time"and all that! I headed to github (https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.16/examples), they had an EJB/Jersey/ReST example. Checked it out, built it and you know what, it worked straight up. This whole business of "no web.xml" is all new to me, surely the world will end without a web.xml? Seems not. Thanks for you assistance!